# How to rotate a vector in opengl?

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, glm-math, 3d-model

I want to rotate my object,when I use glm::rotate.

It can only rotate on X,Y,Z arrows.

For example,Model = vec3(5,0,0)

if i use Model = glm::rotate(Model,glm::radians(180),glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));

it become vec3(-5,0,0)

i want a API,so i can rotate on vec3(0,4,0) 180 degree,so the Model move to vec3(3,0,0)

Any API can I use?

Comment: @Spektre Can you clarify on *"in OpenGL you use glRotate which is quaternion"*? It thought it uses a rotation matrix, no?

Comment: yes,i want a rotation matrix to rotate my object.(4,5,0) is vector

Comment: I give a example,i think you will know what i mean. if a point on (5,0,0) i use glm::rotate (0,1,0) it will become (-5,0,0).i wnat a API to rotate on (4,0,0) so the point become (3,0,0)

Comment: @kevinsu: "*i wnat a API to rotate on (4,0,0) so the point become (3,0,0)*". But... that's not a *rotation*. You can tell because the two vectors have the same direction.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas Why that's not a rotation? (4,0,0)is a vector,where i rotate 180 degree  on it.My point(5,0,0)->(3,0,0).i thing you was misunderstanding.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat My bad it is not quaternion (even if internally might be used to compute that, as Nico Bolas correctly pointed out) I should wrote `glRotate` have 4 input parameters not just 3 .... and it rotates around vector instead of just around base axises (axis aligned incremental rotation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes **OpenGL** uses [4x4 uniform transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) internally. But the `glRotate` **API** uses 4 parameters instead of 3:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glRotatef(angle,x,y,z);
```

it will rotate selected matrix around point `(0,0,0)` and axis `[(0,0,0),(x,y,z)]` by angle `angle [deg]`. If you need to rotate around specific point `(x0,y0,z0)` then you should also translate:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glTranslatef(+x0,+y0,+z0);
glRotatef(angle,x,y,z);
glTranslatef(-x0,-y0,-z0);
```

This is old **API** however and while using modern **GL** you need to do the matrix stuff on your own (for example by using **GLM**) as there is no matrix stack anymore. **GLM** should have the same functionality as `glRotate` just find the function which mimics it (looks like [glm::rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9191219/2521214) is more or less the same). If not you can still do it on your own using [Rodrigues rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula).

Now your examples make no sense to me:

```
(5,0,0) -> glm::rotate (0,1,0) -> (-5,0,0)
```

implies rotation around `y` axis by `180` degrees?  well I can see the axis but I see no angle anywhere. The second (your desired API) is even more questionable:

```
 (4,0,0) -> wanted API -> (3,0,0)
```

vectors should have the same magnitude after rotation which is clearly not the case (unless you want to rotate around some point other than `(0,0,0)` which is also nowhere mentioned. Also after rotation usually you leak some of the magnitude to other axises your `y,z` are all zero that is true only in special cases (while rotation by multiples of 90 deg).

So clearly you forgot to mention vital info or do not know how rotation works.

Now what you mean by you want to rotate on `X,Y,Z` arrows? Want incremental rotations on key hits ? or have a **GUI** like arrows rendered in your scene and want to select them and rotate if they are drag?

**[Edit1] new example**

> I want a **API** so I can rotate `vec3(0,4,0)` by `180 deg` and result
>   will be  `vec3(3,0,0)`

This is doable only if you are talking about points not vectors. So you need center of rotation and axis of rotation and angle.

```cpp
// knowns
vec3 p0 = vec3(0,4,0);  // original point
vec3 p1 = vec3(3,0,0);  // wanted point
float angle = 180.0*(M_PI/180.0); // deg->rad
// needed for rotation
vec3 center = 0.5*(p0+p1); // vec3(1.5,2.0,0.0) mid point due to angle = 180 deg
vec3 axis = cross((p1-p0),vec3(0,0,1)); // any perpendicular vector to `p1-p0` if `p1-p0` is parallel to (0,0,1) then use `(0,1,0)` instead
// construct transform matrix
mat4 m =GLM::identity(); // unit matrix
m = GLM::translate(m,+center);
m = GLM::rotate(m,angle,axis);
m = GLM::translate(m,-center); // here m should be your rotation matrix
// use transform matrix
p1 = m*p0; // and finaly how to rotate any point p0 into p1 ... in OpenGL notation
```

I do not code in **GLM** so there might be some little differencies.

Comment: thanks your reply. I edit my question,hope you know what i mean,if not,I would give more info to you

Comment: @kevinsu api is the same you just need to compute the stuff you need for rotation that is pure math see edit1 also I repaired the translation signs (where inverted)

Comment: Actually I used your method before.but it can't work.because when you translate or rotate in 3D view,it will rotate or translate camera.

Comment: @kevinsu why?  you rotate translate the camera only if you use camera matrix ... if you use this on MODELVIEW matrix then you need to apply this in the right place of code where the transform order will stack up to your model instead of the camera easier is to have 2 separate matrices internally like [Camera Frame and Object Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49841796/2521214) and use the multiplied for rendering but for internal computations like this use your separate matrices .... see the last 3 links in the 4x4 uniform matrix link  there are examples of this ...

Comment: God,I know how to do.thanks a lot.i will give you accept.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat not in GL however in GLM I do not know depends on the notation too if you use inverse matrices instead then yes

Comment: @Spektre Huh. I tried it and indeed you're correct.